# Azure ADX Data Ingestion from Python SDK is failing saying "BadRequest_MappingReferenceWasNotFound" even when mapping is available

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to ingest data into Azure ADX table and using Python SDK's QueuedIngestClient.ingest_from_dataframe(df, INGESTION_PROPERTIES) and data is not inserted.
I have run ".show ingestion failures" and it is shown like `"Mapping reference 'SL_Depth_mapping' of type 'mappingReference' in database 'my-db' could not be found."`. I have this mapping available in the database and the Service Principal is given Ingestor role and AllDatabasesAdmin role.I have validated the input json and mapping and they are working when i try to ingest from the json file using same mapping, below given is the snippet of the code i am using

```
from azure.kusto.data.exceptions import KustoServiceError
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder,ClientRequestProperties
from azure.kusto.ingest import QueuedIngestClient, IngestionProperties, FileDescriptor, BlobDescriptor, DataFormat, ReportLevel, ReportMethod

kcsb_ingest = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(
                self.KUSTO_INGEST_URI, self.CLIENT_ID, self.CLIENT_SECRET, self.AUTHORITY_ID)            

KUSTO_INGESTION_CLIENT = QueuedIngestClient(kcsb_ingest)

INGESTION_PROPERTIES = IngestionProperties(database=self.KUSTO_DATABASE, table=DESTINATION_TABLE, data_format=DataFormat.JSON,
                                                ingestion_mapping_reference=DESTINATION_TABLE_COLUMN_MAPPING, additional_properties=additional_properties)
                
KUSTO_INGESTION_CLIENT.ingest_from_dataframe(df, INGESTION_PROPERTIES)
```

Comment: Please note that mapping names are case-sensitive.
And could you run the following command ".show table <your destination table> ingestion mappings"?

Comment: Thank you @VladikBranevich. I have sorted out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue after some analysis. The actual issue was that the mapping was indeed wrong however the error message made me think that ADX is not able to get the mapping that i provided. Error message was `Mapping reference is not found`.

I was dealing with json data so i created the json based mapping however since i was using `QueuedIngestClient.ingest_from_dataframe` i was providing data in pandas dataframe and QueuedIngestClient was considering data as csv. So i created csv mapping and it worked.

**P.S:** QueuedIngestClient convert dataframe to csv and upload to blob storage and ingestion happen from there!

Comment: Correct. Dataframe is essentially a "DataReader", a tabular representation of your data, so it is ingested as CSV, not as JSON